# Dapper Contrib Insert MySQL Syntax Error

Tags: dapper, dapper-extensions, micro-orm

Hey I am getting syntax error in MySQL using Dapper.Contrib

```
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[cause_code],[cause_name]) values ('000-DDH', 'No Money')' at line 1
```

the correct syntax for Insert in mysql is

```
"Insert Into `tbl_cause` (`cause_code`, `cause_name`) VALUES('blah', 'blah')";
```

my code:

```
var entity = new Cause { cause_code = "000-DDH", cause_name = "No Money" };
        using (IDbConnection cn = ConStr.Conn()) 
        {
            long ins = cn.Insert(entity);
            if (ins > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cause Code: " + entity.cause_code + " Successfully Added!");
                GDRD();
            }
            else {
                MessageBox.Show("Cause Code: " + entity.cause_code + " While trying to Add an Error Occurred!");
            }
        }
```

how to solve this? thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's you again :)
Does the class `Cause` have a `Table("tbl_cause")` directive?
Read the dapper contrib extensions documentation [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/tree/master/Dapper.Contrib)